# ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/rtpostgis-2.4.so": libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am not sure  if this is the right forum for askign this quesiton but saw some similar question around , so posting it here.

I am having trouble in enabling POSTGIS extension in PostgreSQL9.6

when i try to enable POSTGIS:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

I get below error:

> ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.6/lib/rtpostgis-2.4.so":
>   libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory SQL state: XX000

File reported is avaialble under `/usr/lib` as i verified using `find / -name libicui18n.so.58`, the out is as following:

```
/usr/lib/libicui18n.so.58
```

I have build the POSTGIS from source , OS is SLES12 SP2.

Comment: which operating system are you using? could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: Os is Suse 12 sp 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by trial and error but manage to resolve this issue. 
Looks like POSTGIS installation was looking for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` , I resolved it by making sure that my environment `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set and also includes `/usr/lib` in it.

In-case someone else hit the same issue or similar.